# Data Structure for building/demolition history

Tags: java, data-structures, history

here's the problem:
I have to create a program that simulates a city, in particular its buildings, to determinate the average height of its skyline and other values. My problem is choosing data structure: I need something that let me to calculate this values over different years: for example the user could ask for the skyline value in the 2016 and then for the highest building in 2020.

Each building has a String as a key, but once they are demolished, that same key is available again.

This is a project for University, so I'm asking just for a tip; I need to know more "what" and "why" than "how".

I use Java.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a dictionary? You would be able to build and arrange the structure as you see fit. It would be similar to a JSON object or you may integrate a JSON library and use JSON directly

Comment: Use a Database, this is what they're for. If your going to use a key then it should be the address of a building. If a building is demolished then a new record is inserted into the DB Table reflecting that fact. If a new building is erected within the same address or a modification is made to the existing building then yet another record is inserted into the DB Table. Of course the year would be one of the table fields. When requiring information it's just a matter of initiating a specific DB Query.

Comment: I can't use DB due to restriction for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're  looking for a map of multi-level dictionary of some sorts. 
You can have a 2 level dictionary such as { 2018:{height1, height2}, 2002:{} ... }
where each the inner dictionaries are the heights of all the buildings for that year (which is the key). Furthermore dictionaries are fast (although you are trading the performance for space).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, I understand. Is the concept the same even if I have more params in addition (such as distance from the river, width of the base, ecc.)?

Comment: Yes, the concept would be the same. If you will be storing more information for each building, it might be useful to turn each of those "buildings" into objects and store those in the dictionary. As a result you would have a dictionary (where the keys are the years) with an array of "building" objects. You could then iterate over the array and then grab whatever date you need from it. Your dictionary may look something like the following: { 2018: [b1, b2, b2], ..., 2054: [b1, b7, b9]... }

Answer (score 0):

If building keys were unique, you'd have a class like this:

```
class Building
    Key
    Name
    Height
    YearBuilt
    YearDemolished
```

And you could solve your problem with a simple loop over the collection of buildings:

```
for each building
    if (building.yearBuilt <= year && building.yearDemolished >= year)
    {
        // the building was standing during that year
    }
```

If keys can be re-used, you still need to keep the historical information. If you keep it with the building, then you have something like:

```
class HistoricalInfo
    Name
    Height
    YearBuilt
    YearDemolished

class Building
    Key
    HistoricalInfo[]  // some collection (array, list, etc.)
```

And your loop becomes a little more complex:

```
for each building
    for each building.historyInfo
        if (historyInfo.YearBuilt <= year && historyInfo.YearDemolished >= year)
        {
            // this instance of the key was standing during that year
        }
```